# How to Scrape Empty String for those with no Email

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a webpage that has people and their info on it (Phone, Name, Position, Email, etc).  Some of the people are missing either a phone number or email and I'm having trouble with this because I combine lists and if it doesn't scrape a string the indexes will be different.

This is how I'm scraping email:

```
response.xpath('//ul//div[@class="contact-text contact-email ctaType-email"]/a/@title').extract()
```

I'm getting emails from people with this HTML code:

```
<div class="contact-text contact-email ctaType-email">
    <a itemprop="email" href="mailto:test@gmail.com" alt=
  "test@gmail.com" title="test@gmail.com">test@gmail.com</a>                                            
</div>
```

However it's totally skipping over people with this HTML code and messing up my list indexes.

```
<div class="contact-text contact-email ctaType-email">

</div>
```

Is there anyway to make it scrape the empty email address field so I'm able to easily combine fields or add a string into those empty fields?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply split your extraction into two parts:

1. Extract all people nodes
2. For every person node extract email or empty

For example:

```
people = response.xpath('//ul//div[@class="contact-text contact-email ctaType-email"]')
emails = [p.xpath('a/@title').extract() or '' for p in people]
```

Usual approach to avoid issues like these is to extract item nodes and then iterate through them:

```
people = response.xpath('//ul//div[@class="contact-text contact-email ctaType-email"]')
for person in people:
    item = dict()
    item['email'] = person.xpath('a/@title').extract()
    item['something_else'] = person.xpath('...')
    # ...
    yield item
```

Comment: Awesome.  Would i be more efficient to extract all the people nodes and then for each person extract the sub-fields I need?  I've been trying to extract sub-fields then match people to them.  For instance, extract all the names to a list, extract all the phone numbers to a list, and then combine those two lists.

Comment: @Danopi yeah, the most common approach is to extract blocks of nodes. i.e. extract all user nodes and then iterate through each node and find values you need in child nodes. This way is very clear and avoids all sorts of issues like bad combinations, empty values etc - it's just a very clean structure to follow. You can see my edit of what I mean.